# java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module: com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.Jdk8Module not a subtype

Tags: jackson, jersey

In my project We used jersey 2.40 and jackson-core 2.15.2.
When we run this project I get below error.
Exception: A MultiException has 2 exceptions. They are:

1. java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module: com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.Jdk8Module not a subtype
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post construct on org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.internal.DefaultJacksonJaxbJsonProvider

Surprisingly we get this error only in UAT and PROD environmentt. The same code works fine in our DEV, QA environment.
Any help would be appreciated.
Attached the full stacktrace.

2023-07-10 10:04:15,642 WARNING [org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors] (default task-1) The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: HK2 failure has been detected in a code that does not run in an active Jersey Error scope.
WARNING: Unknown HK2 failure detected:
MultiException stack 1 of 2
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module: com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.Jdk8Module not a subtype
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:593)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1244)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1273)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1309)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1393)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear//com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.findModules(ObjectMapper.java:1131)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear//com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.findModules(ObjectMapper.java:1115)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear//org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.internal.DefaultJacksonJaxbJsonProvider.filterModules(DefaultJacksonJaxbJsonProvider.java:80)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear//org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.internal.DefaultJacksonJaxbJsonProvider.findAndRegisterModules(DefaultJacksonJaxbJsonProvider.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear//org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.invoke(ReflectionHelper.java:1268)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear//org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:309)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear//org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:351)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear//org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:463)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear//org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:59)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear//org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:47)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear//org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(Cache.java:74)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear//org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:131)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear//org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache.compute(Cache.java:176)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear//org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:98)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear//org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2102)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear//org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:93)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear//org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:67)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear//org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.AbstractHk2InjectionManager.lambda$getAllServiceHolders$0(AbstractHk2InjectionManager.java:137)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
at java.base/java.util.LinkedList$LLSpliterator.forEachRemaining(LinkedList.java:1242)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear//org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.AbstractHk2InjectionManager.getAllServiceHolders(AbstractHk2InjectionManager.java:141)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear//org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.getAllServiceHolders(ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.java:30)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear//org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getServiceHolders(Providers.java:307)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear//org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getCustomProviders(Providers.java:151)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear//org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.initialize(MessageBodyFactory.java:219)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear//org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientMessageBodyFactory$MessageBodyWorkersConfigurator.postInit(ClientMessageBodyFactory.java:75)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear//org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.lambda$initRuntime$2(ClientConfig.java:463)
at java.base/java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.forEach(Arrays.java:4204)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear//org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.initRuntime(ClientConfig.java:463)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear//org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Values$LazyValueImpl.get(Values.java:317)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear//org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig.getRuntime(ClientConfig.java:829)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear//org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.getClientRuntime(ClientRequest.java:176)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear//org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyWebTarget.onBuilder(JerseyWebTarget.java:371)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear//org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyWebTarget.request(JerseyWebTarget.java:206)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear//org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyWebTarget.request(JerseyWebTarget.java:38)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.commonWebApp.jar//com.sungard.websso.IDPRestClient.getIDPUser(IDPRestClient.java:113)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//com.fis.stcm.userprocess.UserProcessService.getLoggedInUserDetails(UserProcessService.java:46)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//com.fis.stcm.userprocess.UserProcessController.getUserDetails(UserProcessController.java:48)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
at javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final-redhat-00001//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:503)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
at javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final-redhat-00001//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.23.SP2-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.23.SP2-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:111)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.23.SP2-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:67)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.23.SP2-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:111)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.23.SP2-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:67)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.23.SP2-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//com.fis.stcm.security.JwtTokenFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtTokenFilter.java:172)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.23.SP2-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:67)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.23.SP2-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.23.SP2-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:67)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.23.SP2-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.23.SP2-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:67)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.23.SP2-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:126)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:64)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:101)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:119)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.23.SP2-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:67)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.23.SP2-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
at deployment.stnmmear-2023.8.0.14.ear.RestServices.war//org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.23.SP2-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:67)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.23.SP2-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.23.SP2-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.23.SP2-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.23.SP2-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.23.SP2-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@1.9.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.lambda$handleRequest$1(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:68)
at org.wildfly.security.elytron-private@1.15.16.Final-redhat-00001//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.FlexibleIdentityAssociation.runAsFunctionEx(FlexibleIdentityAssociation.java:103)
at org.wildfly.security.elytron-private@1.15.16.Final-redhat-00001//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAsFunctionEx(Scoped.java:161)
at org.wildfly.security.elytron-private@1.15.16.Final-redhat-00001//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAs(Scoped.java:73)
at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@1.9.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.handleRequest(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:67)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.23.SP2-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.23.SP2-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.23.SP2-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
at io.undertow.core@2.2.23.SP2-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.core@2.2.23.SP2-redhat-00001//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.23.SP2-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.core@2.2.23.SP2-redhat-00001//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server-servlet@1.9.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.servlet.CleanUpHandler.handleRequest(CleanUpHandler.java:38)
at io.undertow.core@2.2.23.SP2-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.4.10.GA-redhat-00002//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.core@2.2.23.SP2-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.4.10.GA-redhat-00002//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.23.SP2-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
at io.undertow.core@2.2.23.SP2-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.23.SP2-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:275)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.23.SP2-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:79)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.23.SP2-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:134)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.23.SP2-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.23.SP2-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.23.SP2-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.4.10.GA-redhat-00002//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1555)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.4.10.GA-redhat-00002//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1555)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.4.10.GA-redhat-00002//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1555)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.4.10.GA-redhat-00002//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1555)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.23.SP2-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:255)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.23.SP2-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:79)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.23.SP2-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:100)
at io.undertow.core@2.2.23.SP2-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:393)
at io.undertow.core@2.2.23.SP2-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:852)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.7.SP1-redhat-00001//org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1282)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

Comment: Jersey 2.40 is still hooked with Jackson 2.14. There are some changes in 2.15 that can break the compatibility.